# Vue3 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'main')

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I am trying to make the weather app in Vite , but when I run the program I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'main')". Below is part of the code:

```
  <div id="app" :class="{warm: weather.main && weather.main.temp > 17}">
    <main>
      <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search..." v-model="query" @keypress="fetchWeather" />
      </div>
      <div class="weather-wrap" v-if="typeof weather.main != 'undefined'">
        <div class="location-box">
          <div class="location">
            {{ weather.name }}, {{ weather.sys.country }}
          </div>
          <div class="date">
            {{ dateBuilder() }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="weather-box">
          <div class="temp">
            {{ Math.round(weather.main.temp) }}°c
          </div>
          <div class="weather">{{ weather.weather[0].main }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
```

This my js

```
export default {
  name: "app",
  date() {
    return {
      api_key: '803a7cd7089cd54e3ecc37bf1b6a3340',
      url_base: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
      query: 'Taiwan',
      weather: {
        main: {
          temp: 17
        }
      },
    }
```

my Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmsTQ.png)

Comment: The problem is likely in `weather.weather[0].main`. What's the value of `weather.weather`? It's probably an empty array. That's not shown in your question.

Comment: @tony19 still the same...

Comment: Please update the question to show what you've changed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  <div id="app" :class="weather?.main?.temp > 17 ? 'warm' : ''">
    <main>
      <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search..." v-model="query" @keypress="fetchWeather" />
      </div>
      <div class="weather-wrap" v-if="weather.main != 'undefined'">
        <div class="location-box">
          <div class="location">
            {{ weather.name }}
          </div>
          <div class="date">
            {{ dateBuilder() }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="weather-box">
          <div class="temp">
            {{ Math.round(weather.main.temp) }}°c
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
```

```
export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return {
      api_key: '803a7cd7089cd54e3ecc37bf1b6a3340',
      url_base: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
      query: '',
      weather: {
        main: {
          temp: 0
        },
      },
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line:

```
<div id="app" :class="{warm: weather.main && weather.main.temp > 17}">
```

If you want to use js within the `class=""`, You just have to prepend it by `:`, and not wrap it in `{}`.

Try changing that to:

```
<div id="app" :class="weather.main && weather.main.temp > 17 ? 'warm' : ''">
```

This will result in:

either

```
<div id="app" class="warm">
```

or

```
<div id="app" class="">
```

depending on the condition.

Also, a better way to check for optional properties is to use optional chaining as such:

```
<div id="app" :class="weather.main?.temp > 17 ? 'warm' : ''">
```

Below is a snippet of working code.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1 :class="weather?.main?.temp > 17 ? 'warm' : 'cold'">{{query}}</h1>

</div>

<script>
  const {
    createApp
  } = Vue

  createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        api_key: '803a7cd7089cd54e3ecc37bf1b6a3340',
        url_base: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
        query: 'Taiwan',
        weather: {
          main: {
            temp: 18
          }
        },
      }
    }
  }).mount('#app')
</script>

<style>
  .warm {
    color: red;
  }
  
  .cold {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I did as you said but still the same

Comment: @RossenLin, I added a runnable script of the working code, check what's different from yours.

Comment: Thank you I find the answers.

Comment: @RossenLin what was the problem? Please share so if people have a similar question, they can also see.